# Use INNER JOIN / JOIN for multiple query

Tags: php, mysql, join, pdo, inner-join

What I have at the moment is to match the case from law_case, as in the database scheme below.

[image: The database scheme]

My code:

```
$query1 = "SELECT * FROM law_case WHERE id =?";
$query1vals = array($_GET['id']);
$ids = $adb->selectRecords($query1, $query1vals, false);
$a = $ids['case_type_id'];
$b = $ids['funding_pref'];
#
$query2 = "SELECT type_name FROM case_type WHERE id =?";
$query2vals = array($a);
$ids1 = $adb->selectRecords($query2, $query2vals, false);
$d = $ids1['type_name'];
#
$query3 = "SELECT * FROM expertise WHERE expertise_desc =?";
$query3vals = array($d);
$ids2 = $adb->selectRecords($query3, $query3vals, false);
$c = $ids2['id'];
#
$query4 = "SELECT * FROM individual_expertise WHERE expertise_id =?";
$query4vals = array($c);
$ids3 = $adb->selectRecords($query4, $query4vals, false);
$e = $ids3['individual_id'];
#
$query5 = "SELECT * FROM individual WHERE id =?";
$query5vals = array($e);
$ids4 = $adb->selectRecords($query5, $query5vals, false);
$f = $ids4['network_member_id'];
#
$query6 = "SELECT * FROM network_member WHERE id =?";
$query6vals = array($f);
$ids5 = $adb->selectRecords($query6, $query6vals, false);
```

And what it does is it only gets one network_member.
I want to use INNER JOIN, JOIN or LEFT JOIN and use a while looking to get the different member_name and the URL for each network_member or who's individual has the same expertise_id from the `individual_expertise` table.

I'm new to `JOIN` and tried this code but it doesn't work:

```
$sql = "SELECT member_name, url
FROM individual_expertise
LEFT JOIN individual
USING (individual_id)
LEFT JOIN network_member
USING (network_member_id)
WHERE expertise_id = ?";
$ids3 = $adb->selectRecords($sql, $query4vals, false);

echo $ids3['member_name'];
```

Comment: since you're new to joins, do you know which join you need to use for your situation? INNER JOIN, LEFT JOIN.. so on. I would suggest you read up a bit on Joins and find out what's needed in your case. you can start here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html  and here: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Answer (score 0):

You need to get an overview of `JOIN` types. You have to build a query using `INNER, LEFT, RIGHT, FULL` joins depending on your logical requirements. You can assume that `INNER` join is equal to `&&` or `AND` operators in conditional statements, I mean records must match in both tables.
While, `LEFT` join will return all rows from left table of join and matched rows from right table of join. And `RIGHT` is inverse of `LEFT`. 
And `FULL` join is an example of `||` or `OR` in operators in conditional statements. I mean either a match in both tables.
So you have to join depending on logic you require.

[See here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Do you know the difference between INNER JOIN and LEFT JOIN? I think you don't. You need an INNER JOIN here.

I think this is the right solution for your question:

```
SELECT
    network_member.member_name,
    network_member.url
FROM
    network_member
INNER JOIN
    individual ON individual.network_member_id = network_member.id
INNER JOIN
    individual_expertise ON individual_expertise.individual_id = individual.id
WHERE
    individual_expertise.expertise_id = ?
```

Comment: Thats a good idea, ill try that with a WHERE loop now and see if it gets the different network members :)

Comment: I don't use any GROUP BY clause. Are you sure there are more than one members? Do you use a while-loop to read the query?

Comment: There is more than one individual whos individual.expertise.expertise_id = the same. 

This is the while loop i have
`while($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
      
      echo $row['member_name'], "<br />";
     }`

Comment: Try adding `GROUP BY network_member.id` at the end of the SQL query

Comment: Done that, its only getting one. In the database there are 2.

Comment: I changed to using MySQLi and it does its job.